# Boot live img files in grub

Tags: linux, boot, grub, android

I've compiled a purely 32-bit version of Android that I'm attempting to boot on a device with a 32 bit UEFI.

How the heck do I configure GRUB2 to load a live img file?  The image file contains the following files, generated from `make`:

liveboot.img
intboot.img
autoboot.img

and something here loads the sfs.  How do I pass this through to Grub?

Comment: You might have more success trying to boot it in a virtual machine.

Comment: It boots fine in a VM.  I'm trying to run it natively.

Comment: Tough luck I'm afraid.  You'll have to write it to some kind of disk (I suppose an USB stick would work).